# extract only hour:minute from datetimeindex to x-axis when creating sns.pointplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
                 deploy deployed_today_rent total_rent  cum_deploy  hourly percent  cum_percent
10min                       
2019-10-01 05:30:00 6       0                  0           6    0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 05:40:00 0       0                  0           6    0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 05:50:00 6       0                  0          12    0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 06:00:00 13      0                  0           25   0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 06:10:00 0       0                  0            25  0.000000    0.000000
2019-10-01 06:20:00 0       1                  1            25  0.040000    0.040000
2019-10-01 06:30:00 0       0                  0            25  0.000000    0.040000
2019-10-01 06:40:00 0       1                  1            25  0.040000    0.080000
2019-10-01 06:50:00 1       1                  1           26   0.038462    0.118462
```

from this I am trying to create a pointplot where x-axis is datetime and y-axis is deployed_today_rent.

My code for creating visualization:

```
fig,(ax1, ax2)= plt.subplots(nrows=2)
fig.set_size_inches(22,17)

sns.pointplot(data=test, x=test.index, y="total_rent", ax=ax1,color="blue")
sns.pointplot(data=test, x=test.index, y="deployed_today_rent", ax=ax1, color="green")
ax1.set_xticklabels(test.index, rotation=90,
                     fontdict={
                    "fontsize":16,
                    "fontweight":30
                   })
```

I have two axes in a figure, right now since by x-axis ticks are full datetime and it is rotated 90 degrees the whole tick name is not showing, I want to extract only `05:30:00` from `2019-10-01 05:30:00` and use it on x-ticks. How can I do this?

Also in above `ax1.set_xticklabels` font_weight is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `test.index` in your plot lines, use `test.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S')` this should get you just the `Hours:Minutes:Seconds` from the index.

Your code should be

```
sns.pointplot(data=test, x=test.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), y="total_rent", ax=ax1,color="blue")
sns.pointplot(data=test, x=test.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), y="deployed_today_rent", ax=ax1, color="green")
```

Comment: hm... This seems legit but for some reason it is not working.

Comment: runs without an error however still renders same graph

Comment: it is working for me just fine. double check the dataframe names & column names.